# Rebuilding Mac Photos Face Profile?

Tags: mojave, photos

In Photos on the Mac (Mojave), we have a face file with thousands of photos in it. Apparently, someone misidentified one of our kids (Person A) for another (Person B) in hundreds of those photos. It would be a huge amount of work to go through and re-identify a bunch of photos in the face file as not being Person B.

We deleted the profile in Faces for Person B, but when we look at the the photos, they're still identified as Person B.

Is there way to reset all these photos to "unnamed"? Or to rebuild all the faces from scratch, without losing all our other metadata?